# How to Intercept incoming SMS, even when the app is force stopped by user

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I want my app to intercept the incoming SMS, even when my Application is force stopped by user.

Currently I have enabled BroascastReceiver by Using below class

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         Bundle pudsBundle = intent.getExtras();
         Object[] pdus = (Object[]) pudsBundle.get("pdus");
         SmsMessage messages =SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);    
         Log.i(TAG,  messages.getMessageBody());


}
```

And by declaring the permission and receiver in the manifest,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

<receiver android:name="com.XXX.SMSReceiver" android:exported="true">
<intent-filter android:priority="999">
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
</intent-filter>
```

The problem I am facing is my app is unable to listen to BroadCast Receiver, when user force stop the app.

Is there any alternate way to solve this issue?? Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: have you add permission in manifest?

Comment: If the user forcibly stops your app, it's put back into the _stopped_ state, and your Receiver won't work until the user runs your app again (since API 3.1). There's nothing you can do about that.

Comment: @SohailZahid : added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

Comment: As Mike said, you can't for a reason. Only thing you could do (only to prevent accidentally force-closes) is to remove your app from recents or hide the launcher.

Comment: @JacksOnF1re, thats a helpful workaround, can you point out how can this be achieved ,